# Retrieving category pages from subcategory returns empty sets

Tags: wp-query, categories, loop, pages

I've a category overview page. It shows its subcategories. These subcategories have subsubcategories which are pages too. I'd like to retrieve those (title, permalink and excerpt) but so far my `WP_Query` is not returning any results.

My current PHP is

```
<?php 
//Find subcats of cat
$cat = get_category_by_slug($pagename); /* ="MORE" */
$catid = $cat->cat_ID;
$subcats = get_categories(array('orderby'=>'term_group','parent'=>$catid)); /* GROUP 1 GROUP 2 ... */
//$subcatCnt = rank order of subcat within cat
$h1cnt = 1;
foreach($subcats as $subcat){
    $subcatid = $subcat->cat_ID;
    echo "\r\n\r\n\r\n" . '<h1 id="' . $subcat->slug . '">bla' . $subcatid . $subcat->name . '</h1>';

    $cat_args = array(  'post_type'         =>  'page',
                        'cat'               =>  $subcatid,
                        'posts_per_page'    =>  3);

    $cat_pages = new WP_Query($cat_args);

    if ($cat_pages->have_posts()){ /* BUT THEY SOMEHOW DON'T HAVE ANY POSTS :-( */
        while ($cat_pages->have_posts()){
                $cat_pages->the_post();
                echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>';
        }
    }
```

In the browser, the right subcategories show up with their ID's but they seem to contain no subsubcategories:

[image]

I then checked `term_taxonomy` to confirm that subsubcategories are under the right category. This holds.

[image]

I looked up these `term_ids` in my DB and they're correct too:

[image]

How can I make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. What does *"These subcategories have subsubcategories which are pages too"* mean? It looks like you are trying to query for pages which have been associated to each subcategory.

Comment: @Milo: I created pages for some categories. These pages show overviews of posts under the category of the page. A (live) example is http://www.spss-tutorials.com/basics/. So this works for posts but I'm now trying to do the same for pages. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: how are these pages related to the categories? you are querying for pages that are IN each subcategory.

Comment: @Milo: I think pages relate to a category via the category's `slug`. The `slug` URL is the URL for an overview page.

Comment: it sounds like you should be querying for pages by `pagename` matching category `slug`.

Comment: @Milo: the categories have subcategories (which don't exist as pages). These are shown as `<h1>` titles on the category page. I'd like to query for pages from these subcategories instead of their parent (main) categories. I didn't formulate my initial question very well by the way. Perhaps I should rewrite it.